# Почему вывод нулевой?

Tags: java

Есть один глупый вопрос. Почему выводом нижеуказанной программы является 0. 
Код:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Testing

{

    public static void main(String[] argv)

    {
        Stack stack   = new Stack();
        Mov   mov     = new Mov();
        System.out.println(stack.getSize());
    }
}

class Mov

{

    private int c = 0;
    public Mov()
    {
        Stack stack   = new Stack();
        for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
            c++;
            stack.push(c);
        }    
    }        
}

class Stack

{

    private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public void push(int c)
    {
        list.add(c);
    }        
    public int getSize()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Testing

{

    public static void main(String[] argv)

    {

        Mov   mov     = new Mov();
        Stack stack   = move.getStack();
        System.out.println(stack.getSize());
    }
}

class Mov

{

    private int c = 0;
    public Mov()
    {

    }        
    public Stack getStack() {
    Stack stack   = new Stack();
        for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
            c++;
            stack.push(c);
        } return stack;    
    }

}

class Stack

{

    private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public void push(int c)
    {
        list.add(c);
    }        
    public int getSize()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

}
```

как-то так что-ли)

Comment: Спасибо. Я понял.

Answer (score 0):

В конструкторе класса Mov() вы совершаете действия с временным объектом, не со stack, который создаётся в методе main().

Comment: я бы не назвал стек внутри мува - временным объектом, но то что объект стек внутри мува и в мейне - разные объекты - факт =)

Comment: Разве он не уничтожается при выходе из конструктора?

Comment: Как, в таком случае, можно получить необходимый вывод в main(в данном случае 15) и можно ли это сделать в принципе, используя этот простой подход?(Под этим простым подходом, я подразумеваю сохранение значения в отдельном буферном классе с возможностью получения этого значения в любом месте программы).

Comment: В main — никак (по-крайней мере, мне это кажется в данном контексте чем-то весьма непростым). А почему не вариант перенести строчку "System.out.println(stack.getSize())" в конец конструктора Mov()?

Comment: В данном случае - может и вариант, но меня интересует сам принцип переноса значений из одного класса в другой используя класс на подобии Stack.

Comment: Вынесите `Stack stack;` в члены класса `Mov`, сделайте для него геттер `getStack()`. В мэйне вызывайте:

    System.out.println(mov.getStack().getSize());

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто, ты вызываешь метод getsise() у Объекта stack,
 в котором не было создано ни обного объекта Mov, следвательно, вопрос,
 как в стеке окажутся данные если ты их туда не положил??)) Поэтому и выводит в результате, что размер стека равен 0 =)